# Synonyms to ‘semi thick’?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

What is the synonym to ‘semi thick’ body? When someone describes their body shape as semi thick, what does he mean? Thank you.

Comment: ...maybe "stout", or "chunky"

Comment: Semi-thin perhaps?

Comment: Hello Veronica, welcome to EL&U. 'Thick' is not usually applied to bodies in English. German speakers often use 'thick' for 'fat' when speaking English as the German for 'fat' as in 'a fat man' is 'dick' so 'thick' becomes a False Friend for German speakers of English. I can only guess that a person who refers to his body as 'semi thick' means that he is 'a little overweight' but i really can't be sure. It's not something that a native speaker would say.

Comment: I would say "gooey".

Comment: I don't know what *semi thick* means. If it's somewhere between *thin* and *thick*, isn't that just *average*? Or does it mean somewhere between *average* and *thick*? Come to think of it, I don't know what *thick* means in this context. *Overweight*? *Obese*? *Heavyset*? *Muscular*? Before being able to determine a synonym for the term, you have to explain what the term itself means. And also why one synonym would be better than another.

Answer (score -1):

**Unfortunately, you're dealing with a "fad phrase"**

We live in a funny world where we simply can't stand using the words and phrases our ancestors (read: "parents") used.  Part of the problem is we increasingly want to avoid insulting, offending, or otherwise shaming people who might not (or do not) fit the concept of "perfect" (whatever that actually is).  Thus, what was once "fat" or "heavy" became "curvy" or "dad bod" because the earlier words grew increasingly negative in context.

*This is a common practice in the marketing industry as advertisers look for ways to pleasantly sell products intended for heavier body shapes.*

I believe this is the case with the phrase "semi-thick" in relation to body shape.  I see the phrase "thin-thick" more often, usually to describe the combination of an <s>impossibly</s> thin waist with <s>overweight</s> wide hips and buttocks.

"Semi-thick" appears to be most often used to describe a person who has a square body shape and/or is somewhat overweight (as Cascabel said, "stout" or "chunky") such that the body appears to be a bit more than it normally would be (like using **bold type**) but does not favor actual obesity.

To make matters worse, the phrase has been used for a much longer period of time to describe fluids and objects.  A syrup or shampoo has a "semi-thick body" meaning it will pour slowly or can be manipulated somewhat like a cream once dispensed.  Writing instruments, art brushes, even drum sticks will be described as having a "semi-thick body" meaning the objects can still be used comfortably like their thinner counterparts but carry greater weight or fit more fully in the crook between the thumb and the palm.  Because it's been used this way for a longer period of time, it's more difficult to narrow down how the "fad phrase" use for body shape is used.

Which is the problem with "fad phrases" (words or phrases invented for the moment).  Their definition is rarely specific and often modulates over time.  A semi-thick body shape this morning could be more or less when compared to the use of the same phrase later in the evening.  (In this regard, social media is having a *profound* affect on how language is used.)